# Adding an existing database table to a EF6 Code first repository

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have an Entity Framework 6 code first application. As a one-off, I want to add a entity class based on a table that has been added externally to the database originally generated from the code first application. I know how to do this manually, but I wondered if there is a tool or method that could generate the class for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new project, right click on it -> Add new item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> Database first

Then let entity framework generate models for your database and just copy the one you need to your project. That's probably the easiest solution :)